# Overwrite CSS Using JavaScript / jQuery Permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to overwrite CSS file permanently using JavaScript / jQuery?
I want to overwrite just 1 or 2 lines though.

Let's say I have this CSS file:

```
div#box { width:100px; height:100px; }
```

then, if I apply this kind of JavaScript:

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = "div#box {width:200px;}";
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
```

the div only resized as long as the JavaScript is called (dynamically changed by JavaScript)

I want the CSS file would be overwritten like this

```
div#box {width:100px; height:100px; }
div#box {width:200px; } //CSS added
```

or more nicely,

```
div#box {width:200px; height:100px; } //CSS overwritten
```

What should I do?

Thx :D

Comment: javascript is a client side scripting language, and the file sits on the server

Comment: And just changing the stylesheet (css file) is not an option?

Comment: actually, I want to make dynamically resizeable div and store it by overwritting the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on what has been said (And mmmshuddup and calchen are correct):

Javascript alters files on the client side until the document is closed. The changes that scripts make are entirely temporary.

However, javascript *could* technically use ajax to access a perl/ruby/php/python/whatever script hanging out on the server which would take arguments (What the class would be, which element it would be added to) and apply the classes permanently to your documents, or otherwise edit your style documents.

Another solution would be creating and adding classes and then saving those classes as preferences for a user; you'd create a function which looked through an associative array of element id's and their classes that need to be added upon the page being loaded. I suppose you'd use either cookies or preferably a database for this, if you have users at all. I'm just throwing hypotheticals out there.

I'm pretty sure the server-side editing idea is your best option. It would probably be pretty safe to use regex to locate id's and replace them with the new style.

edit: Upon thinking about it, I realized your style finding and replacing function would have to be pretty sophisticated if you ever wanted to do replacements of styles that involved a lot of selectors. There is probably a more elegant solution, but it's not coming to me. I think this would be a serious headache eventually.

Comment: It really depends on _how often_ this type of change would have to be made to a CSS file. If he expects to write changes to the file itself every time something changes like a page edit or something (who knows) then it might actually be worth writing a server side script for this. Otherwise, javascript is the best solution (besides just manually changing the CSS file I guess). IMO

Comment: Also, if he used PHP to overwrite a CSS file, then the next thing to consider is _when will the changes be viewable to the user_? If the file has been cached then he would have to set the appropriate response headers (like Cache-Control etc) to ensure that the user sees the new version of the CSS file right away.

Comment: Yeah, I'm certainly not advocating doing what I've described. Considering the trouble it would be to get this working *without* worrying about what you mentioned, it seems incredibly impractical and I can't see why it would be necessary. I just figured I'd shed some light in the directions one could take to accomplish this. I've definitely never seen someone do this before.

Comment: I think both of your idea by using server side scripting is doable. In width/height case, maybe the temporary changes would be directly viewable by using jqueryui-resizeable, and at the same time the permanent changes would be stored by calling php function to overwrite css. I'll try it. thx :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS cannot be permanently overwritten using only jQuery/JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
$(document).ready (function() {

$('div#box').css( {"border": "1px solid #7F9DB9", "width": "200px", "height": "22px"} );

});
```

Please do needful changes.

Answer (score -1):

Use something like PHP. Otherwise you can modify the css with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

```
// for div#box {width:200px; height:100px; }
$('div#box').css({ width: '200px', height: '100px' });
```

Answer (score -1):

JS can't do this alone, you need the use of a server side language such as PHP, i can make one for you in PHP if you'd like.

If you want to do it on a per page basis you can use a style tag with contenteditable attribute see: http://devgrow.com/html5-contenteditable-attribute/